# Oracle - Delete dmp files from ASM diskgroup

Tags: oracle, linux, scripting, export, oracle-asm

I want to delete my export files daily from ASM diskgroup with a crontab job. I want to prepare a script for it.

```
ASMCMD> ls
exp1.dmp
exp2.dmp
exp3.dmp
exp4.dmp
ASMCMD> pwd
+DATA/EXP
```

How can I prepare this script? I prepared a template for it, but I couldn't script it.

```
set_gridenv
asmcmd
cd +DATA/EXP
rm -rf exp*.dmp
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did a small test.

```
# find some ASM files
asmcmd find DATA/T101N/AUTOBACKUP/2020_09_20/ \*
+DATA/T101N/AUTOBACKUP/2020_09_20/s_1051641713.313.1051641713
+DATA/T101N/AUTOBACKUP/2020_09_20/s_1051658719.331.1051658719

# remove them one-by-one
asmcmd rm DATA/T101N/AUTOBACKUP/2020_09_20/s_1051641713.313.1051641713
asmcmd rm DATA/T101N/AUTOBACKUP/2020_09_20/s_1051658719.331.1051658719

# they are gone
asmcmd find DATA/T101N/AUTOBACKUP/2020_09_20/ \*
ASMCMD-8002: entry 'AUTOBACKUP' does not exist in directory '+DATA/T101N/'
```

Your scenario should be similar:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set grid home
. oraenv <<< +ASM

# delete dump-files
asmcmd rm -rf DATA/EXP exp\*.dmp
```

Best of luck!